# Help Forwarding Ports

Tags: port-forwarding

For example, I have an ONT optical fiber with two Ports.

- Port 1 connects to the router (Int IP: 192.168.0.1) (Ext IP: 190.6.206.171), the router assigns me an internal IP for the Web Server (192.168.0.11 -> 190.6.206.171).
- Port 2 connects to the mail server (Ext IP: 190.6.206.173).

  How difficult here, I need all the webserver send mails (192.168.0.11) THROUGH send them mail server (190.6.206.173)

Any Idea :) ?

Comment: Without knowing what type of router you have ... there is no way we can help you

Comment: Dlink Dir-100 :)

Comment: Currently, the NAT router is properly configured and works perfectly, my only drawback is that makes the Webserver is inside the router (192.168.0.11) sends mail using the external mail server (190.6.206.173).

Comment: If I understand the question, you  have your webserver sending mail through your mail server instead of sending mail itself.  If that is the case, we'd need to know more about your setup.  I suspect whatever you are using to send emails on the web server can be told what SMTP server to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your web server and/or its application(s) to send SMTP emails via 190.6.206.173. Likewise, you should be able to ping 190.6.206.173 from your web server.